# Time based Collision Detection in Anddengine?

Tags: android, andengine

i am creating a game where a moving ball is collides with a hole.
and then remove the ball from scene.
i implemented successfully this using

```
if (ball.collidesWith(hole)) {
    //remove ball
}
```

but i need a timer delay that if ball collide with hole for continue 3 sec then remove the ball otherwise not.
could anyone tell me how to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a counter to add miliseconds into a private variable in your class.

```
if (ball.collidesWith(hole)) {
   counter+=elapsedtime; //add time since last call
}else
   counter=0;
}
```

in your update method include this:

```
if(counter>=3000)
{
//remove ball
}
```